# How to create a model from a specific table that is inside a schema using peewee orm? (FastAPI Project)

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, peewee

I need to create a model from a table that is inside a schema in my db using the orm peewee, I found a command that allows me to generate all models from my database in postgresql

```
python -m pwiz -e postgresql db_name > db_name_models.py
```

but I only need to create the model of a specific table, which is inside a schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line option provided
http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz

Use the **-t** option to mention the table(s)

```
python -m pwiz -e postgresql db_name  -t tablename, tablname2 > db_name_models.py
```